# Windows - Opening a webserver on a VM in vmware

Tags: windows, apache

New to setting up webservers from scratch, was used to IT taking of these things for me

I figured out how to setup Apache and creating dummy websites via localhost. This is what I have so far -

- Created a Windows 11 VM, using VMWare
- Installed Apache using chocolatey, and configured a `VirtualHost`, and added a new entry under `hosts` file, and I can visit the dummy domain locally on the VM
- Now I am trying to visit this domain from my host machine (eventually from the outside world). And followed the instructions here - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2006955, but no luck.

I've searched for videos on youtube, but most of them are for linux os'. Can someone kindly guide me how to reach the dummy domain from my host machine please

Comment: You don't give folks much to go on with your problem description.  You should probably post the exact error you are receiving and maybe your Apache configuration.

Comment: @JJF I know, apologies. I don't have much information to post I am afraid. I just enabled `vhosts` path in the `httpd.conf` file, and added a new `VirtualHost` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file, and then added the dummy domain to `hosts` file, looked straight forward until now. It's the part after this one I am not sure how

Comment: @JJF so was to get it working. The same setup works fine with a Windows Server OS. Will try to figure out why it isn't working if I run Apache on Windows 11 OS later

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what it is 100% yet, but the same setup works fine on a Windows Server 2016 OS ‍♀️

Thinking it's prolly firewall and stuff on Windows 11 OS, will try to figure it out a bit later. Crisis averted for now